# Enable a child form and disable a control in MDI parent

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, mdichild, menustrip, mdiparent

I have a MDI parent form and I have a menustrip on it.
I am loading my MDI child form in it. Then I am trying to disable the menu strip in the form load event of mdi parent form. but it gives me an unhandled exception. the inner exception says null. 
This is what I tried.

```
FormControllers.FrmLogin newLogin = new FormControllers.FrmLogin();
                newLogin.MdiParent = this;

                newLogin.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
                newLogin.Show();
                this.MainMenuStrip.Enabled = false;
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: You'd better call you newLogin form using ShowDialog().

Comment: "inner exception" is pretty weird.  I'd guess you are running this code too soon, before the MDI parent is initialized.  Hmm.  Stack trace required.

Comment: @Nick showdialog gave me this exception.Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling showDialog."}

Comment: @chathwind - sorry misread that one - will delete now